# Про присваивание двух указателей на один адрес

Tags: c++, указатели

Есть переменная `x` типа `unsigned long long`.

Есть указатель на неё: `ull *px = &x;`

Мне требуется хоть каким-то образом, если это конечно возможно, сделать указатель типа `char` на тот же самый адрес - на адрес `px`.

Можно ли это сделать? Если да, то как?

Comment: вроде [`reinterpret_cast<char *>(px)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), либо просто [`(char *) px`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

Comment: @diraria Большое человеческое спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
unsigned long long x = 0;
unsigned long long * px = &x;
char * c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(px);
```

Comment: Благодарю... :)

Comment: BTW, некоторые авторы рекомендуют `static_cast<unsigned long long*>(static_cast<void*>(px))`, не знаете, в чем фишка?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Откровенно  говоря, особой разницы не вижу - только чтоб `reinterpret_cast` не использовать, но вряд ли тут будет какое-то отличие de facto...